# Why DPI info returned as (1,1) while image properties show it as (96,96)?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff, dpi

I extracted raw data from pdf files and converted the first page of PDF into Tiff/Jpeg/PNG in python. By leverging the popploer package.

```
images = convert_from_path(file[i],poppler_path=r'C:\Users\User\poppler-0.68.0_x86\poppler-0.68.0\bin')
images_first_page=images[0]
images_first_page.save('C:/Users/User/Documents/folder' +'.tif', 'TIFF')

img = Image.open('C:/Users/User/Documents/../...tif')
print(img.info)
```

Result:

```
{'compression': 'raw', 'dpi': (1, 1), 'resolution': (1, 1)}
```

However, looking at the image property:

[image: screenshot of image properties]

It shows it as 96 dpi, 96 dpi, Not sure what `(1,1)` means in my case.

Comment: "By running" - so what code did you run?

Comment: @ForceBru
img = Image.open('C:/Users/User/Documents/.../....tif')
print(img.info)
{'compression': 'raw', 'dpi': (1, 1), 'resolution': (1, 1)}

Comment: Please put your code in your question, not down here in the comments.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the tip, added.

Comment: Please check the [mre] help section, and (also) provide the code for the PDF to TIFF conversion, as well as some exemplary PDF, if that error only occurs for some, but not all of your inputs.

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks for the tips, edited the question.

Comment: Not knowing anything about your files it’s hard to give an answer. But my guess is that the file doesn’t have a DPI value, and some software will give you 96 DPI as the default, and other software will give you 1 as default.

Comment: The `tiffinfo` tool will tell you if the resolution TIFF tag is actually set or not in the file, and what its value is.

Comment: See Cris's comment above. Note also that `exiftool` can also tell you. As can **ImageMagick** with `magick identify -verbose IMAGE.TIF`